# How do I view previous diff commits using Git?

Tags: git, diff

How do I view previous diff commits using Git?

I have a file that I've made several commits on, but I want to view previous versions of the file AND its diff's at different stages. Seeing where I made mistakes and how I fixed them is really helping my code. By the way, I'm using Tower as a GUI on top of Git.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
git log --full-diff -p your_file_path
```

Check out: 
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Comment: `--full-diff` will give all the files in those commits. This may be too much information if you are looking for just the `-p` patches made to a particular file. It may be useful to see all the files changed at the same time as they may be related to the one you are looking at.

Answer (score 42):

You need `git log`. If you were interested in file `SOMEFILE` use

```
$ git log -p SOMEFILE
```

The `-p` option displays the patch which is probably the diff you are looking for.

Comment: I think this answer more directly answers the question.

Answer (score 37):

If you don't want to specify a particular file, and see the diff for *all* files changed, just use

```
$ git log -p
```