# Extract Git diff for multiple commits based on commit message

Tags: git

I would like to extract the diff of all commits that pass a certain regex in their messages.

For example:

- Commit 4: "**JIRA-12** Deleted Something" **diff4**
- Commit 3: "**JIRA-13** Modified something" **diff3**
- Commit 2: "**JIRA-13** Added Another thing" **diff2**
- Commit 1: "**JIRA-12** Added something" **diff1**

I would like to be able to get the diff for all the commit that have `JIRA-12` in their messages.

I imagine I should type something like `git diff --message "*JIRA-12*"` that would give me **diff1 + diff2**.

Is there a Git command that does that? Or are there other means to do that?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901300/how-do-i-view-previous-diff-commits-using-git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log --grep <REGEX HERE> -p`

The `--grep` option allows you to find only the commits that match the given regex.

To get the diff for each of the commits add the `-p` or `--patch` option.  This shows the changes that were included in each of the commits.

I believe that this will get you what you are looking for.